# PHP array_multisort is not sorting the second array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my code:

```
$numbers = array(10, 100, 100, 0);
$names = array("Alex", "Jane", "Amanda", "Debra");
array_multisort($numbers, $names);

print_r($numbers);
print_r($names);
```

The above code outputs:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 0
  [1] => 10
  [2] => 100
  [3] => 100
)

Array
(
  [0] => Debra
  [1] => Alex
  [2] => Amanda
  [3] => Jane
)
```

Why is the sorting of second array incorrect? If it is correct, could anyone explain how is it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. You are taking PHP's 'array_multisort' function in wrong way. It will not sort both arrays, but will sort the first array and the second array will have positioning in order corresponding to first array.

$numbers Before sort:

```
(
  [0] => 10
  [1] => 100
  [2] => 100
  [3] => 0
)
```

After sort:

```
(
  [0] => 0 (position before sorting - 3rd)
  [1] => 10 (position before sorting - 0)
  [2] => 100 (position before sorting - 2 or 1)
  [3] => 100 (position before sorting - 2 or 1)
)
```

So, the second array will not get sort but will get its elements positioned according to first array.

```
(
  [0] => Debra --in first array 3rd element has moved to 0th position
  [1] => Alex -- in first array 0th element has moved to 1st position
  [2] => Amanda -- in first array 2nd element has moved to 2nd position
  [3] => Jane -- in first array 1st element has moved to 3rd position
)
```

Comment: Ty for the explanation, I would like to now why its then even possible to add sorting parameters for both arrays ? So if I would add to the second array SORT_STRING it wouldn´t affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of `array_multisort`. The first array is sorted, and the second array is reoraganized so its values continue to correspond to the same values of the first array. Note that where the first array has equal values (the two `100`s), the second array's values are sorted internally (so `Amanda` comes before `Jane`).

If you want to sort two arrays independently, you could just use two [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) calls.

Answer (score 0):

its easy :
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,

                $numbers, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC);

print_r($names);

Comment: Won´t work, same result, just print numbers and you see that one is wrong.

Comment: it was for me :
 Array ( [0] => Alex [1] => Amanda [2] => Debra [3] => Jane )

Comment: Yes but check the numbers array, print_r($numbers) it will be wrong.

Comment: array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);<br>
array_multisort($numbers);

Comment: Then you use multisort twice, this is a completly different thing and would work. Anyway question is answered so this is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's **array_multisort** works to sort first array and arrange second array according to the items of first array rather sort both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although that might be an answer I would suggest giving an working example for the OP. If not someone might flag this answer.

Answer (score 0):

$numbers = array(10, 100, 100, 0);
$names = array("Alex", "Jane", "Amanda", "Debra");
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);
array_multisort($numbers);

print_r($names);
print_r($numbers);